# Performance between `(Enum)(object)e` and `e as Enum` where e is struct

Tags: c#, .net

I was just curious to see what was faster:

- `(Enum)(object)e`
- `e as Enum`

`e` is an enum value-type, specified through a generic type parameter.

I started profiling these with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new DateTimeKind[] { DateTimeKind.Local, DateTimeKind.Unspecified, DateTimeKind.Utc };
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        while (true)
        {
            sw.Restart();
            for (var i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
                ToSeparatedCommaStringAs<DateTimeKind>(list);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("AS    " + sw.ElapsedTicks);

            sw.Restart();
            for (var i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
                ToSeparatedCommaStringCast<DateTimeKind>(list);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("CAST  " + sw.ElapsedTicks);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static string ToSeparatedCommaStringAs<T>(T[] enums)
        where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        var commaString = string.Empty;
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Tipo de enums é inválido");

        foreach (var item in enums)
        {
            Enum enumerador = item as Enum;
            commaString += enumerador.GetStringValue() + ",";
        }

        return commaString.TrimEnd(',');
    }

    public static string ToSeparatedCommaStringCast<T>(T[] enums)
        where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        var commaString = string.Empty;
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Tipo de enums é inválido");

        foreach (var item in enums)
        {
            var enumerador = (Enum)(object)item;
            commaString += enumerador.GetStringValue() + ",";
        }

        return commaString.TrimEnd(',');
    }
}

public static class EnumExt
{
    public static string GetStringValue(this Enum value)
    {
        return "nome"; //só para testar
    }
}
```

I was surprised to discover that the *cast* version was running faster on my machine. Others have tested with different results. Some say that the `as` operator is always faster and others say it varies from run to run.

I have analysed the disassemlby window while running, and the codes are different:

```
Lines with an `x` were in fact executed:

              Enum enumerador = item as Enum;
x 001E349D  mov         ecx,707E5288h  
x 001E34A2  call        000C30F4  
x 001E34A7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-34h],eax  
x 001E34AA  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
x 001E34AD  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
x 001E34B0  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],edx  
x 001E34B3  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
x 001E34B6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-58h],eax  
x 001E34B9  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-58h]  
x 001E34BC  mov         ecx,707CF474h  
x 001E34C1  call        715D0260  
x 001E34C6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax  
  
  
  
              var enumerador = (Enum)(object)item;
x 001E39F0  mov         ecx,707E5288h  
x 001E39F5  call        000C30F4  
x 001E39FA  mov         dword ptr [ebp-34h],eax  
x 001E39FD  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
x 001E3A00  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
x 001E3A03  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],edx  
x 001E3A06  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
x 001E3A09  mov         dword ptr [ebp-38h],eax  
x 001E3A0C  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-38h],0  
x 001E3A10  je          001E3A31  
x 001E3A12  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
x 001E3A15  cmp         dword ptr [eax],707CF474h  
x 001E3A1B  jne         001E3A22  
  001E3A1D  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
  001E3A20  jmp         001E3A2F  
x 001E3A22  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
x 001E3A25  mov         ecx,707CF474h  
x 001E3A2A  call        715D2582  
x 001E3A2F  jmp         001E3A34  
  001E3A31  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
x 001E3A34  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax
```

Why the results differ so much... the cast version does a box operation, it should be slower... isn't it?

**EDIT:**

I have now compiled in Release mode and run it without a debugger and raised the process priority.
The times are like this:

```
AS    21305328
CAST  20655717
AS    20330474
CAST  20714744
AS    23156667
CAST  21187540
AS    19841935
CAST  20838702
AS    20180793
CAST  20498759
AS    20782600
CAST  20454898
AS    19819178
CAST  20294181
AS    20244950
CAST  20241214
AS    20919664
CAST  20771469
AS    19990283
CAST  21707570
AS    19759742
CAST  20667567
AS    20259063
CAST  21602690
AS    20200280
CAST  20668826
AS    20147201
CAST  20048725
AS    19845383
CAST  20226356
AS    20169406
CAST  20401720
AS    20826775
CAST  20114984
AS    20691103
CAST  21552342
AS    20200982
CAST  20858057
AS    19734088
CAST  20266943
AS    19589351
CAST  20477856
AS    19813852
CAST  20350659
AS    20180603
CAST  20307336
```

**Question continuation**

I found out that `Enum` is a reference type... can someone confirm that `e as Enum` will box the value of `e`, the same way that `(Enum)(object)e` will. As `Enum` is a reference type, it should... The only way for this to be false, is in case the runtime treats `Enum` as something special (like it does with `Nullable<T>`).

What I thought previously:

- `e as Enum` will not box anything, and should be faster
- `(Enum)(object)e` is doing a box operation, and should be slower

What I suspect that is true:

- `e as Enum` will do a box operation
- `(Enum)(object)e` will do a box operation
- as both will box the value, both should be comparable in performance

Comment: Can you provide running times? About what difference are we speaking? 0-2% is reasonable if you run it in non-scientific conditions.

Comment: Benchmarking microoptimizations is *extremely* hard.  When you're dealing with timings this small all sorts of things come in to play that don't when performing sensible benchmarks.  In short, the "noise" of your system, along with the costs of the benchmarking code itself, isn't negligible as it is when benchmarking things that are actually doing real work.  Unless you both really know what you're doing, and are working on *particularly* sensitive programs, just don't waste your time with microoptimizations that you're going to struggle to even measure the effects of.

Comment: @CommuSoft I have compiled it in Release mode, without attached debugger, and times favored more the `as` version... but not as much as I expected. I'll post the timings.

Comment: The times you've printed shows pretty clearly that the background noise of your system is significantly greater than any differences between the two operations.  You should treat them as functionally identical as far as performance goes.

Comment: @Servy I though boxing should cost a lot. That's the motivation of this question. At first, the cast version did a little better... but after the last test, it seems really impossible to test this.

Comment: Creating a new instance of an object (which is what boxing is) is an *extremely* fast operation.  You just need to move the heap pointer up a fixed amount and assign some values to those bits.  There aren't a whole lot of things you could ever do in your application that will be faster than that.  And of the object doesn't survive through even a single GC (which an object like this almost certainly never will), it adds no additional work for the GC.

Comment: I think I found what was confusing me... `e as Enum` is also boxing the enum value... so both versions will do a box operation, not only `(Enum)(object)e`.

Comment: I think the IL would be far more revealing than the assembler.  Maybe you could ILspy it to learn something?  I imagine there might be a box opcode in there?

Comment: Also, the differences are teeny-weeny, tiny.  Problem is your question is about performance differences, which you've proven to be negligible and unimportant.  Weirdly if you rephrased it to ask about the mechanism and differences in how the code is compiled and IL is generated, it might be more palatable to SO :)

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Maybe my intention was not clear. I wanted to know why the result was not as expected... not to squeeze performance out of it. I'll try ILspy... thanks!

Comment: Your benchmark is measuring 99% *other* stuff! The boxing is a tiny part of it. that's why the differences are tiny. 99% are the same for both versions. There even are generics in the mix which you must remove as well. They have impact.

Comment: @usr I thought generics would make a difference only in the first run, when being JIT compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments the performance measures and timings are so close to each other it's hard to say that one of the castings is faster than the other. Taking a look at the generated IL code explains why the performance is reasonliby to eachother.

When using the `(Enum)(object)e` casting it is boxed. After that it uses the  `castclass` OpCode. This pushes an object onto the stack then pop it from the stack and cast it the `Enum` class, or any other class if you want. The new created object is pushed onto the stack.

When using the `e as Enum` casting it is boxed also. After that it uses the `isinst` OpCode. The difference between the `isinst` and the `castclass` is that the `isinst` checks if the pushed object reference from the stack can be passed into the class. If it cannot be passed it returns null. When it succeeds it behavious like an `castclass`.

IL Code `isinst`

```
IL_0039: stloc.1
IL_003a: nop
IL_003b: ldloc.1
IL_003c: box !!T
IL_0041: isinst [mscorlib]System.Enum
IL_0046: stloc.2
IL_0047: ldloc.0
IL_0048: ldloc.2
```

IL Code `castclass`

```
IL_0039: stloc.1
IL_003a: nop
IL_003b: ldloc.1
IL_003c: box !!T
IL_0041: castclass [mscorlib]System.Enum
IL_0046: stloc.2
IL_0047: ldloc.0
IL_0048: ldloc.2
```

Hope this helps with you're question.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass.aspx